# Extraer URL de imagen en HTML usando expresión regular (regex)

Tags: php, regex

Resulta que trato de extraer una imagen de esta forma:

```
$url = 'https://m.fa.com/perfil123';//cualquier perfil
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0); //visualizar ñ y acentos.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip,deflate"); //(aceptación de codificación gzip)   
$url = curl_exec($ch); //almacena el response de la pagina.

curl_close($ch);
    preg_match('#class="bo img" src=[^"]*"([^"]*)"#', $url, $datos)
$img = $datos[1];

echo $img;
```

Este es el HTML de la imagen que busco :

```
<img width="72" height="72" alt="" class="bo img" src="https://scontent-mia3-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/cp0/e15/q65/p74x74/21151613_1725782907724134_7535903357386699205_n.jpg?efg=eyJpIjoiYiJ9&amp;oh=4f22a577f965566b2016ef842f5b110f&amp;oe=5A1DE043">
```

Estoy ocupando la **`class`** para definir la imagen pero no sé en qué parte está el fallo.

Comment: Esto es mucho más sencillo de resolver usando DOM. Si bien se puede resolver con regex, no es una herramienta buena para procesar HTML. Siempre va a haber alguna excepción a cualquier regla. Para eso se usa DOM. ¿No te conviene olvidarte de regex y usar lo que corresponde?

Comment: Por otro lado, tu regex [coincide con la imagen de tu ejemplo](https://regex101.com/r/wtobcq/1)... ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: @Mariano existen otras imágenes en el html por eso uso como referencia **class="bo img"** para extraer esa única imagen pero no funciona  ni de esta manera preg_match('#class=\"bo img\" src=[^"]*"([^"]*)"#', $url, $datos) y la verdad no logro entender el motivo .

Comment: Deberías agregar más partes de tu código y más texto del HTML, porque el problema no está en lo que publicaste. Podés verlo funcionando en --> http://rextester.com/DASNG77336

Comment: Gracias lo seguiré intentando se que el problema se encuentra en la class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Con regex (no recomendado)

Como te comenté, la expresión regular que estás usando coincide perfectamente con el HTML de tu pregunta ([ver demo](http://rextester.com/DASNG77336)). Sin embargo, usar regex para esto no es lo recomendado. Por ejemplo:

- no estás considerando que esté dentro de una etiqueta `<img>`, por lo que con `<input type='text' value'class="bo img" src="url.jpg"'>` *tendrías un problema... y se puede solucionar fácil, pero...*
- con tener otro atributo entre la clase y la URL, como por ejemplo `class="bo img" data-ejemplo="bla" src="url.jpg"` *tendrías un problema... y se puede solucionar fácil, pero...*
- con sólo alterar el orden de las clases a `class="bo img"` *tendrías un problema... y se puede solucionar fácil, pero...*
- si esa parte del HTML está comentada, como por ejemplo en `<!-- <img class="bo img" src="url.jpg"> -->` *tendrías un problema... y se puede solucionar, pero...*
- **siempre va a haber alguna regla poco convencional en la sintaxis de HTML que te complique todo**, y que haga que tu regex no coincida por algo que no pensaste que podía ocurrir.

Probablemente sea más indicado modificarla a algo como: <kbd>[Ver en regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FzBQIr/2/)</kbd>

```regex
#<img\b(?=[^>]*\sclass\s*=\s*"(?=[^"]*\bbo\b)[^"]*\bimg\b)[^>]*\ssrc\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"#i
```

pero aún así, fallaría en muchos casos.

---

#### Utilizando DOM (recomendado)

No deberías usar expresiones regulares para procesar HTML. Al nivel que estás planteando tu expresión, tan sólo un pequeño cambio en el HTML haría que tu regex falle. Un espacio de más, un cambio en los atributos del tag, un comentario, o estructuras más complejas, harían que hasta un regex gigantesco no siga las reglas. Incluso con una expresión muy avanzada, se podría generar un caso casi a prueba de fallos, pero casi siempre podría encontrar un caso *raro* que haga que falle. Además, requeriría un experto cada vez que quieras modificarlo.

Es muy sencillo procesar HTML con **[DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)**, son las herramientas que están pensadas para eso.

Si tenemos un HTML como el siguiente:

```php
$html = '
    <img class="img" src="ejemplo1.jpg">
    <img width="72" height="72" alt="" class="bo img" src="https://scontent-mia3-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/cp0/e15/q65/p74x74/21151613_1725782907724134_7535903357386699205_n.jpg?efg=eyJpIjoiYiJ9&amp;oh=4f22a577f965566b2016ef842f5b110f&amp;oe=5A1DE043">
    <img class="bo etc" src="ejemplo2.jpg">
    <img class="bo etc img" src="ejemplo3.jpg">
';
```

Simplemente se genera el DOM así:

```php
//Englobamos en body para corregirlo y que lo procese bien
$html = "<body>$html</body>";

//Generar el DOM
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_NONET | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

Y podemos obtener todas las imágenes dentro del DOM con:

```php
$img_nodelist = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
```

Para recorrerlas con

```php
foreach ($img_nodelist as $img) {
    // ...
}
```

Obteniendo las clases de cada una con:

```php
$clases = $img->getAttribute('class');
```

y la URL de la imagen con:

```php
$urlImagen = $img->getAttribute('src');
```

> Nota: también se puede buscar con XPath, que es mucho menos código (y seguramente se ejecute algo más rápido), pero preferí explicarlo así, más explícito, para que sea más claro.

**Código:**

```php
//Ingreso
$html = '
    <img class="img" src="ejemplo1.jpg">
    <img width="72" height="72" alt="" class="bo img" src="https://scontent-mia3-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/cp0/e15/q65/p74x74/21151613_1725782907724134_7535903357386699205_n.jpg?efg=eyJpIjoiYiJ9&amp;oh=4f22a577f965566b2016ef842f5b110f&amp;oe=5A1DE043">
    <img class="bo etc" src="ejemplo2.jpg">
    <img class="bo etc img" src="ejemplo3.jpg">
';

//Englobamos en body para corregirlo y que lo procese bien
$html = "<body>$html</body>";

//Generar el DOM
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_NONET | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);


//Obtener todas las imágenes
$img_nodelist = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

//Recorrer cada una
foreach ($img_nodelist as $img) {
    //Obtener la lista de clases
    $clases = $img->getAttribute('class');
    $clases_arr = explode(' ', $clases);

    //Ver si contiene ambas clases
    $clases_buscadas = array('bo', 'img');
    if (!array_diff($clases_buscadas, $clases_arr)) { //Contiene las clases
        //Obtener el SRC
        $urlImagen = $img->getAttribute('src');
        echo "URL: $urlImagen\n";
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
URL: https://scontent-mia3-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/cp0/e15/q65/p74x74/21151613_1725782907724134_7535903357386699205_n.jpg?efg=eyJpIjoiYiJ9&oh=4f22a577f965566b2016ef842f5b110f&oe=5A1DE043
URL: ejemplo3.jpg
```

Demo:

<kbd>[Ejecutar en 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/OYNce)</kbd>

Comment: Excelente respuesta solo me resta una duda si quisiera buscar esa imagen dentro de una url (documento html) como lo logro con **DOM** Donde pongo la url . gracias

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions no me quedó del todo claro. ¿Querés buscar dentro de un `<a href="...">`? ¿O ver si existe una imagen específica con una URL conocida dentro del HTML? Podés editar la pregunta agregando el ejemplo y lo aclaro en la respuesta

Comment: O si la pregunta es cómo cargar el HTML de una web, loadHTML te permite pasarlo como parámetro como `$dom->loadHTML($url, LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);`. Le saqué una de las opciones, y en ese caso no hay que agregarle el `<body>`. Fijate la info en http://php.net/manual/es/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Comment: estoy buscando como utilizar tu ejemplo . ya actualice la pregunta para que entiendas

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions si la respuesta de la página contiene la imagen, cualquiera de las dos opciones que respondí funciona. Sin embargo, puede ser que estés recibiendo una respuesta de Facebook como usuario que no inició sesión (sin la imagen)... Eso ya es otro tema completamente diferente, en donde te convenga usar la API de Facebook directamente. Deberías comprobar qué se imprime como respuesta de CURL.

Comment: gracias ya entiendo y tendré que ocupar la api de facebook . y se que es otro tema  por mi parte solo me resta darte las gracias por tu aclaración y dar el tema por serrado . saludes